# label text cropped with border with CornerRadius setted maui

Tags: border, maui, cornerradius

when I set a *CornerRadius* in a **Border** the **Label** that is the Content of the **Border** is being cropped.
This only happens when i run the program in windows, adroid works fine, ios I don't know.

```xml
<Grid BindingContext="{TemplateBinding Content}">

    <Border x:Name="foodTypeContainer"
            MinimumWidthRequest="80"
            MaximumHeightRequest="140"
            Padding="8,0,8,0"
            Stroke="Transparent"
            BindingContext="{Binding .}">
        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20" />
        </Border.StrokeShape>

        <Label x:Name="foodTypeTextLabel"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="RubikLight"/>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Cropped Label Text in Border]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a known issue with Maui at the moment, maybe you should use Frame for the moment until this is fixed

More information about the issue can be found on this Github bug I raised a couple of days ago:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17753

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17761

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17763